# HTML div not centered though flex is used

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created the following list within a div that is centered by flex.
As you can see in the snippet, the list is not centered (as I would expect with using flex on the `list-div2` and the `translate` rule in the parents `middle-text` `div`.
Can someone help me? Why does it not get centered properly?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.container>div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.container>div .content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.half-width {
  width: 50%;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third>img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.middle-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third>.middle-text>.list-div2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third>.middle-text>.list-div2 li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  visibility: visible;
  list-style-type: bullet;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width">
    <div class="content">
       <div class="third-parent">
         <div class="third" id="one">
           <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=left">
          </div>
        <div class="third" id="two">
          <div class="middle-text">
            <h1>Headline</h1>
                  <div class="list-div2">
        <ul class="items-list2" id="list">
          <li>Entry A</li>
          <li>Entry B</li>
          <li>Entry C</li>
          <li>Entry D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third" id="three">
          <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=right">
        </div>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please narrow down the question and delete any code which is irrelevant?

Comment: It's because 'ul' default add padding and margin in it,  so just add css for that `ul {padding: 0; margin: 0}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give     `padding: 0;` to your `ul`

```
ul.items-list2 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

The [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#section-lists) says ul has as default margin of 40px, but different browsers over ride this. So its always good to normalize margins and paddings.

[image: UL padding]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul.items-list2 {
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.container>div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.container>div .content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.half-width {
  width: 50%;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third>img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.middle-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third>.middle-text>.list-div2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third>.middle-text>.list-div2 li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  visibility: visible;
  list-style-type: bullet;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width">
    <div class="content">
       <div class="third-parent">
         <div class="third" id="one">
           <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=left">
          </div>
        <div class="third" id="two">
          <div class="middle-text">
            <h1>Headline</h1>
                  <div class="list-div2">
        <ul class="items-list2" id="list">
          <li>Entry A</li>
          <li>Entry B</li>
          <li>Entry C</li>
          <li>Entry D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third" id="three">
          <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=right">
        </div>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because of the padding/margin that browsers add to the `ul` tag by default.

Example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.container>div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.container>div .content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.half-width {
  width: 50%;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third>img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.middle-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third>.middle-text>.list-div2 {
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.full-width>.content>.third-parent>.third>.middle-text>.list-div2 li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  visibility: visible;
  list-style-type: bullet;
}

.items-list2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width">
    <div class="content">
       <div class="third-parent">
         <div class="third" id="one">
           <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=left">
          </div>
        <div class="third" id="two">
          <div class="middle-text">
            <h1>Headline</h1>
                  <div class="list-div2">
        <ul class="items-list2" id="list">
          <li>Entry A</li>
          <li>Entry B</li>
          <li>Entry C</li>
          <li>Entry D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third" id="three">
          <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=right">
        </div>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks +1 for the solution and +1 for the explanation:)

Answer (score 2):

Actually user agent stylesheet have padding left. So you need to overwrite that style by ul{padding-left: 0}

```
ul, menu, dir {
   display: block;
   list-style-type: disc;
   -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
   -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
   -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
   -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```